# How can I play sound when a expandable list view child is clicked in android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to play sound when a child list is clicked.

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandablelistview, View clickedView, 
                               int groupPosition, int childPosition, long childId) {
       switch (childPosition) {
                case 0:
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.beep1);
                    mp.start();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.beep17);
                    mp.start();
                    break;

            }
        return false;
   }
});
```

I tried this but this isn't unique for each child, as I want to play different sound for each child.
Please let me know if there is a way to attach sound to each list child.
thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest to use SoundPool, not MediaPlayer for you short samples

Answer (score 1):

You could attach it as a [tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) to each child view.

> A tag can be used to mark a view in its hierarchy and does not have to be unique within the hierarchy. Tags can also be used to store data within a view without resorting to another data structure.

When clicked, you retrieve it with [getTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()) and play it.

Although I would not try to attach the sounds themselves if you have too many views, as they might fill up your memory depending on the length. I would rather set the tag to a string identifying the sound, and get the sound object itself from somewhere else.

Comment: How do i do that pls?

Comment: Setting and getting the tag, through the methods I've linked in my answer. For playing the sound, read the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) documentation, follow the examples, and if you run into problems, you can always write another question including what you've done so far.

Comment: Its not the method i am not getting ... its the implementation...where to do the attachment for starters?